# Optimising binary serialization for multi-dimensional generic arrays

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, binary

I have a class that I need to binary serialize. The class contains one field as below:

```
private T[,] m_data;
```

These multi-dimensional arrays can be fairly large (hundreds of thousands of elements) and of any primitive type. When I tried standard .net serialization on an object the file written to disk was large and I think .net is storing a lot of repeated data about element types and possibly not as efficiently as could be done.

I have looked around for custom serializers but have not seen any that deal with multi-dimensional generic arrays. I have also experimented with built-in .net compression on a byte array of the memory stream following serializing with some success, but not as quick / compressed as I had hoped.

My question is, should I try and write a custom serializer to optimally serialize this array for the appropriate type (this seems a little daunting), or should I use standard .net serialization and add compression?

Any advice on the best approach would be most appreciated, or links to resources showing how to tackle serialization of a multi-dimensional generic array - as mentioned [existing examples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/FastSerializer.aspx) I have found do not support such structures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.  The code below makes an int[1000][10000] and writes it out using the BinaryFormatter to 2 files - one zipped and one not.

The zipped file is 1.19 MB (1,255,339 bytes)
Unzipped is 38.2 MB (40,150,034 bytes)

```
        int width = 1000;
        int height = 10000;
        List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            list.Add(Enumerable.Range(0, width).ToArray());
        }
        int[][] bazillionInts = list.ToArray();
        using (FileStream fsZ = new FileStream("c:\\temp_zipped.txt", FileMode.Create))
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\temp_notZipped.txt", FileMode.Create))
        using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(fsZ, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
            f.Serialize(gz, bazillionInts);
            f.Serialize(fs, bazillionInts);
        }
```

I can't think of a better/easy way to do this.  The zipped version is pretty damn tight.

I'd go with the BinaryFormatter + GZipStream.  Making something custom would not be fun at all.

---

[edit by MG]
I hope you won't be offended by an edit, but the uniform repeated Range(0,width) is skewing things vastly; change to:

```
        int width = 1000;
        int height = 10000;
        Random rand = new Random(123456);
        int[,] bazillionInts = new int[width, height];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < width;i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                bazillionInts[i, j] = rand.Next(50000);
            }
```

And try it; you'll see `temp_notZipped.txt` at 40MB, `temp_zipped.txt` at 62MB. Not so appealing...

Comment: There are 2 problems with this; the first is that the OP asked about rectangular (not jagged). The more important is that your compression is being affected by the uniform data. I'll add a sport of random to show what I mean...

Comment: Of course you cannot compress random data. But lots of meaningful data can be reasonably compressed. So by my opinion compression can be appealing.

Answer (score 0):

The best code length/output size ratio would be to encode your array using BitConverter, converting all elements into their compact binary format. It's manual, I know, but will save 80-90% space compared to .NET binary serialization.

Comment: However, BitConverter is a pain to use with generics (you'd need to use reflection, presumably joined with Delegate.CreateDelegate for efficiency), and doesn't work for all types (not even all the inbuilt structs)...

Answer (score 0):

Can you define "large"? The 1000x10000xint example (another post) comes out at 40Mb; and 1000x10000x4 bytes (=int) is 38MB. As overheads go, that isn't terrible.

What sort of data is T likely to be? Just primatives?
I'm thinking that I could probably edit [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) to support rectangular arrays`*` - but to keep some kind of wire-compatibility we'd probably need a header (one byte) *per element* - i.e. 9MB of overhead for the 1000x10000 example.

This probably isn't worth it for things like `float`, `double`, etc (since they are stored verbatim under "protocol buffers") - but there may be savings for things like `int` simply due to how it packs ints... (especially if they tend to be on the smaller side [magnitude]). Finally, if T is actually objects like `Person` etc, then it should be a *lot* better than binary serialization, since it is very good at packing objects.

It wouldn't be trivial to shoe-horn in rectangular arrays, but let me know if this is something you'd be interested in trying.

`*`: it doesn't at the moment since the "protocol buffers" spec doesn't support them, but we can hack around that...

Comment: Thanks very much for your thoughts on this Marc. I looked into protobuf-net and it looks very interesting. For my class there will be a lot of repeated/redundant data so I'm thinking standard binary serialization plus compression should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The reason there needs to be so much data about the types is that your array of T could be any type, but more specifically, T could be of type SomeBaseClass, and you could still store SomeDerivedClass in that array, and the deserializer would need to know this.

But this redundant data makes it a good candidate for compression, as others have noted.