# Reading data file into an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, grid, file-handling

I have an array like this:

```
    int[,] iMap = new int[iMapHeight, iMapWidth] { 
                 { 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
                 { 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
                 { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    };
```

And I want the same thing coming from a data file. The file should be structured like this preferably:

```
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000
```

Which will ultimately make an array like above with all values set to 0.

What would be the best way to do this? Would I read one line from the file and then split each characters separately and transfer it to the new array? Or perhaps read a line, and then read each character and put that in the array?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you looked into binary serialization? This thread seems along similar lines. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223700/c-optimising-binary-serialization-for-multi-dimensional-generic-arrays  Also the accepted answer from this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/90c98754-2580-404a-81ae-aedba5f2604d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, assuming that the array has a fixed size :

```
int[,] iMap = new int[iMapHeight, iMapWidth];
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < iMapHeight; i++)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        for(int j = 0; j < iMapWidth; j++)
        {
            iMap[i, j] = (int)(line[j] - '0');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an 'index out of range' exception when I use your code. It looks like it'd work but I'm looking through it now trying to figure it out. Especially the `(int)(line[j] - '0');` bit, Im not sure where you split the characters in the line to be put into separate array entries. But thank you very much :)

Comment: `line` is a line ; `line[j]` is the character at position `j` ; `line[j] - '0'` is the integer represented by that character (i.e. '0' => 0, '1' => 1...)

Comment: Regarding the IndexOutOfRangeException, check that the number of lines in the file and the length of the lines are correct

Comment: OK, got it... the condition in the second loop was wrong. I fixed it, it works now

Comment: Should of noticed that myself :) Thanks. Only problem is now I get this error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the line: `iMap[i, j] = (int)(line[j] - '0');`.

Comment: perhqps because `line`  is null... check that your file has enough lines